# Loci of intersection of lines with positive intercepts??

Tags: coordinate-systems, locus

[image]

How does one go about proving the equation of the curve that is formed by tracing the intersection of the lines with each other?

Comment: What curves, lines are you talking about? Those diagrams aren't very clear.

Answer (score 3):

These are **quadratic Bezier curves** obtained by joining regularly spaced points on two line segments.

See paragraph "string art" in

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

The curve is called an **envelope**.

The envelope of a family of straight lines is the curve, if it exists, having these straight lines as its tangents.

There is a general method that allows to compute the envelope of a family of straight lines (or more generaly a family of curves depending on a parameter $p$). Let us take one of the examples you have displayed in convenient axes i.e., with unit segments $[0,1]$ on x-axis and y-axis, resp.

The equation of the straight line joining point $(p,0)$ to point $(0,1-p)$ is:

$$\dfrac{x}{p}+\dfrac{y}{1-p}=1$$ or, simpler

$$(1-p)x + p y = p(1-p) \ \ $$

(say, for $0 \leq p \leq 1$).

Let us write down the equation obtained by equating the derivatives of the two sides with respect to parameter $p$ (*partial derivative*, which means that $x$ and $y$ are considered as constants), and group this second equation with the first one:

$$\begin{cases}(1-p)x + p y & = & p(1-p)\\
 -x+y & =  &1-2p \end{cases}.$$

and now solve this parametric system to get an expression of $x$ and of $y$ as  functions of $p$, i.e.,

$$\begin{cases} x & = & p^2\\ 
y & = & (1-p)^2\end{cases}.$$

which, in fact, describes a parabola with its axis 
tilted at 45 degrees.

Remark:  The method of derivatives is not magic: there is a rather easy proof for it. I present it now.

---

**Edit**: Why do we take partial derivative with respect to parameter $p$ ?

Let us use a reasoning that dates back to the 18th century.

We take 2 infinitely close straight lines of the same family, with equations:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}  f(p)x + g(p) y & = & h(p) & \ \ \ \ & (1) \\ f(p+dp)x+g(p+dp)y & =  &h(p+dp) & \ \ \ \ & (2) \end{matrix}\right.$$

We consider that their point of intersection is arbitrarily close to the envelope curve, thus in fact is part of the envelope.

This system (1)+(2) is equivalent to the system obtained by keeping (1) and replacing (2) by the difference (2)-(1) (equivalence because one can go way and back from the first system to the second one), that is:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}  f(p)x + g(p) y & = & h(p) & \ \ \ \ & (1) \\ (f(p+dp)-f(p))x+(g(p+dp)-g(p))y & =  &h(p+dp)-h(p) & \ \ \ \ & (2') \end{matrix}\right.$$

Dividing now the second equation by $dp$, we obtain the derivatives of coefficients $f(p), g(p), h(p)$ as we have done in the above example.

Remark: the resulting linear system

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}  f(p)x + g(p) y & = & h(p) & \ \ \ \ & (1) \\ f'(p)x+g'(p)y & =  &h'(p) & \ \ \ \ & (2') \end{matrix}\right.$$

will have solutions for all $p$ such that:

$$\begin{vmatrix} f(p) & g(p) \\ f'(p) & g'(p) \end{vmatrix} \neq 0$$

Comment: thanks for your answer. I didn't understand the differentiation with respect to p. Please do not postpone the presentation any further :P

Comment: All right, I will add an "Edit" to my answer.

Comment: I wish I could add another upvote for the edit. Very nice!

Comment: @pjs36 I appreciate  :)

Answer (score 0):

If two straight lines at an inclination $\alpha $ are each divided into $n$ equal parts from points $P,Q$ on them to their intersection point $O$ and serially connected by straight lines in reverse order, then they include between them a parabolic envelope (touching locus) with $P,Q$ as points of tangentcy.

Example: (when $ \alpha= \pi/2 )$:

Points on $x-,y-$ axes and sub-divisions:

$$ P= (0,b) ; Q ( a,0); p (0,b\, t) ; q ( a(1-t),0);  $$

Variable line connecting points$(p,q)$

$$ \frac{x}{a(1-t)} + \frac {y}{b \,t} = 1 \tag{1}$$

To eliminate $t$ by $C-$ discriminant method, partially differentiate w.r.t. $t$ and eliminate from (1),

$$ \frac{x}{a(1-t)^2} = \frac {y}{b \,t^2}  \tag{2}$$

Eliminating $t$ between (1) and (2), we have the parabola tangential to axes at the intercepts.

$$  \sqrt{\frac{x}{a}} + \sqrt{\frac{y}{b}} = 1.  \tag{3} $$

which are typical of the two graphs at left.