# Total area of rectangle rotation

Tags: geometry, area, envelope

### Question:

The rectangle $ABCD$ is rotated into a rectangle $A′B′C′D′$.

Initial state $A$ is at the origin, $B$ is on the y-axis $D$ is on the x-axis.

During the rotation, $A$ travels vertically along the $y$
-axis until it meets $A′$.

While $D$ simultaneously travels horizontally along the $x$
-axis until it reaches the origin.

(The x-axis and y-axis can be understood as impenetrable walls).

The length of the short side is $h$ and the length of the long side is $w$.

Find the total area swept during this process.

### My Attemptions

I drew the following diagram, $ABOC'$ area is $h^2$.

But I don't quite understand what the arc $\overset{\frown}{B'C}$ looks like, I don't know how to get an expression for this curve, either in parametric equation form or implicit equation form.

[image]

Comment: You need to specify exactly how the rectangle moves from the initial position to the final position.  All you have said is $A$ is "close to" the $y$-axis and that description is mathematically imprecise.  An example of a precise statement would be to say that $A$ travels vertically along the $y$-axis until it meets $A'$, while $D$ simultaneously travels horizontally along the $x$-axis until it reaches the origin.  Such a motion is a combined rotation and translation, but it is not the only possible way in which the rectangle can move, which is why you need to unambiguously specify it.

Comment: @heropup I suppose the part _'$A$  is close to the y-axis, and $D$ is close to the x-axis'_ means the two points slide along indicated lines, exactly as you described. Possibly OP is not a native English speaker (neither am I), hence the unfortunate expression 'close to an axis'. :)

Comment: What is the education level, at which you get this problem to solve?

Comment: @CiaPan I have given two interpretations in my "answer" below. As the candidate mentions "envelopes", I think the issue should be treated at undergraduate level.

Comment: @GalAster: Referring to Jean Marie's first sketch. If I understood the motion ok, it is a sliding rectangle instead of a ladder. $ a=3,h=2.$; HINT: The curves have equations;$ \sqrt {x}+\sqrt {y}=\sqrt {a}$ and $(X-x)^2+(Y-y)^2 =h^2 .$ Asteroid and " Asteroid Bertrand Parallel"; 
A segment length ( width of rectangle) 2 along common normal can be dragged on a curve midway between the two curves to find swept area by Pappu's theorem.

Comment: The asteroid implicit equation can be also written $ x^2+y^2+a^2 -2ax -2 xy -2 ay =0 $

Comment: @Narasimhan The ast(e)roid cannot have such an equation $x^2+y^2+a^2 -2ax -2 xy -2 ay =0$ because this is the equation of a conic curve. Neither the equation $\sqrt {x}+\sqrt {y}=\sqrt {a}$ : in fact it is $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=a^{2/3}$ ; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid).

Answer (score 2):

After our exchange, I have understood you mean the type of "rotation" given in the figure below. Caution : it isn't a rotation in the usual sense of the word because this transformation hasn't a center (which should be an invariant point) : see the second interpretation in the "Comment" below.

[image]

*Fig. 1 : The sides of the moving rectangle "envelope" curves. The North-East curve generated by line segment $[B_tC_t]$ is a piece of astroid : see the classical "sliding ladder image" for example [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Astroid.html). The North curve is divided into two parts : an arc of the black curve with equation given below in (1) and an arc of the red curve which is an ellipse with parametric equations given in (2).*

Using the technique of envelopes it is possible to get the equation of the envelope of line $A_tB_t$ (black curve on fig. 1). Here is the way I have proceeded :

I start from the equation of line $A_tB_t$ which is :

$$x \cos t - y \sin t = -w (\sin t)^2 \tag{a}$$

I differentiate (1) wrt parameter $t$, considering variables $x$ and $y$ as constant, giving, after a sign change :

$$x \sin t + y \cos t = 2 w \sin t \cos t \tag{a'}$$

Solving system (a) + (a') gives the parametric equations of the envelope  (black line) of moving *line* $A_tB_t$ :

$$\begin{cases}x&=&\tfrac12 w \sin(t)\sin(2t)\\y&=&\tfrac12 w \sin(t)(3+\cos(2t))\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

But in fact, we deal with a moving *segment* which is not the same as a moving line ; as a consequence, there is a kind of "competition" (I haven't found a better word) with the (small) elliptic arc issued from the  locus of $B_t$, itself a quarter of an ellipse (red curve) with equation :

$$\begin{cases}x&=&h \sin(t)\\y&=& w \sin(t)+ h \cos(2t)\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

Please note that in (2), both parameters $w$ and $h$ are present whereas in (1), only $w$ is present.

In fact, we have to do the same kind of calculations for $B_tC_t$. Can you take it from here ?

Fig. 1 has been generated by the following Matlab program  :

```
 clear all;close all;hold on;
 axis([0,2.4,0,2.4]);
 axis equal tight
 w=2;h=1; % rectangle's height and width
 for t=0:pi/50:pi/2
     b=w*cos(t);c=i*w*sin(t);d=h*i*exp(-i*t);
     R=[b,b+d,c+d,c,b]; % rectangle : complex coord.
     c='g';
     if t==0;c='b';end;
     plot(real(R),imag(R),'color','c','linewidth',2);
 end
     t=0:pi/50:pi/2;
     plot(w*(sin(t).^2).*cos(t),w*sin(t).*(1+cos(t).^2),'k','linewidth',8);
     plot(h*sin(t),w*sin(t)+h*cos(t),'r','linewidth',8)
     text([0.,0.,w,w,h+0.05],[0.1,1.1,1.1,0.1,w],{'A_0','B_0','C_0','D_0','B_1'})
```

---

**Comment** : here is a different interpretation of your question with a true rotation around center $(w/2,w/2)$ :

[image]

*Fig. 2 : Axes are in black. The center of rotation is materialized by a little circle.*

The swept area can be computing rather easily because it can be decomposed into circular sectors.

(in fact, I don't think it is the kind of transformation you had in mind).

Matlab program having generated figure 2 :

```
 clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal;
 w=3;h=1; % length and width of rectangle
 C=[w/2;w/2]; % center
 plot(C(1),C(2),'ok')
 R=[0,w,w,0,0
    0,0,h,h,0]; % rectangle's vertices
 for t=0:-pi/50:-pi/2
    M=[cos(t),-sin(t);sin(t),cos(t)]; % rot. matrix
    X=M*R+((eye(2)-M)*C)*ones(1,5); using transl. by C
    plot(X(1,:),X(2,:),'linewidth',4);
 end
 plot([0,w],[0,0],'linewidth',8,'color','k');
 plot([0,0],[0,w],'linewidth',8,'color','k'); % axes' plots
```

Comment: It is your first diagram. It seems that the next step is to find the boundary conditions of Astroid. Should it be integral between $h-\operatorname{arccot}\frac{w}{h}, w+\operatorname{arccot}\frac {w}{h}$.

Comment: Or should I use the polar coordinate equation? The graph is symmetric, and the polar coordinates just need to be integrated in two segments and then multiplied by 2

Comment: Happy you have reacted and said in particular which interpretation was the good one. I don't think polar equations are the good solution. I think you should parametrize for example line segment $A_tB_t$ for $0<t<1$ and use the technique of derivation wrt to parameter $t$ as described for example in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3075558/305862). Same operation for line segment $B_tC_t$.

Answer (score 1):

The figure below is a .GIF image showing the sliding/rotation of the a rectangle that has $w = 10$ and $h = 5$.

[image]

The upper black curve is the trajectory of vertex $B$ and the right black curve is the trajectory of vertex $C$.  The green curve is the envelope of $AB$ while the pink curve is the envelope of $CD$.  The blue curve is the envelope of $BC$ while the red curve is the envelope of $AD$.

If $t$ is the angle (in radians) that side $AD$ makes with the $x$ axis, then the equation of the trajectories of $B$ and $ C $ are

$B(t) = (h \sin t , h \cos t + w \sin t ) $

$ C(t) = (w \cos t + h \sin t , h cos t ) $

The green curve is given by

$ P_{AB}(t) = (w \cos t - w \cos^3 t , 2 w \sin t - w \sin^3 t ) $

Then pink curve is given by

$ P_{CD} = (2 w \cos t - w \cos^3 t , w \sin t - w \sin^3 t ) $

The blue curve is given by

$ P_{BC} = (h \sin t + w \cos^3 t , h \cos t + w \sin^3 t ) $

To find the area swept by the sliding/rotating rectangle, we need to find numerically two points:

1. The intersection point between $P_{AB}(t)$ and $B(s)$. I got the intersection point numerically to be $(3.828361, 10.87288)$ at $t = 0.997414, s = 0.872086$
2. The intersection point between $P_{BC}(t)$ and $B(s)$. I got the intersection point numerically to be $(4.981225, 10.39535)$, at $t = 1.358781, s = 1.484109$.

The area enclosed is determined by the integral

$ A = \dfrac{1}{2} \displaystyle \int x(t) y'(t) - y(t) x'(t) \ dt $

where the integral is segmented into three parts corresponding to $P_{BC}(t), B(t)$, and $P_{AB}(t)$.

With the found values of intersection between the curves, the area integral is

$\text{Area} = \displaystyle \int_{\pi/4}^{1.358781} (-h^2 + 3 w^2/8 ) + hw \sin(2 t) \\ \displaystyle - 3/8 w^2 \cos(4 t) \ d t \\ \displaystyle + \int_{1.484109}^{0.872086} - h^2 \ dt \\ \displaystyle + \int_{0.997414}^{\pi/2} w^2 (\frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{2} \cos(2t) + \frac{3}{8} \cos(4t) ) \ dt $

This integral evaluates to

$\text{Area} = 89.26953 $

Comment: [+1] I hadn't noticed your answer. A caveat : I have remarked that the figure is case-dependent; according to the ratio w/h, the relative positions of the green, black and blue arcs can change.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes.  This is indeed the case.